# How to get current time in nanoseconds in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get current time in nanoseconds in node.
I tried the following function, but it's not working.
Is there any other way to do it?

```
function getNanoSecTime() {
    var hrTime = process.hrtime();
    return hrTime[0] * 1000000000 + hrTime[1];
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: maybe it depends on node version?

Comment: Just be aware the process functions won't run in a browser environment. Just on the off chance you're running your script in the browser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node has built in functionality to get time with nanoseconds. here is the examples of get nanoseconds

**Node.js 10.7.0+** - Use

```
process.hrtime.bigint()
```

**Rest Versions** - Use

```
process.hrtime()
```

Comment: do we need to import process or we can directly use it?

Answer (score 1):

To get the current time in nanoseconds as a `bigint`, you can use the following built-int function:

```
process.hrtime.bigint();
```

See the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processhrtimebigint)

Answer (score 0):

Install with npm:

`$ npm install --save nanoseconds`

then :

```
const nano = require('nanoseconds');
console.log(nano(process.hrtime()));
```